# Is it possible to query this on mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is it possible to query this? I have 2 tables.

```
tithing table
Tithing_ID = PK

tithingspayment table
TP_ID = PK
Tithing_ID = FK to tithings table "Tithing_ID"
Paid_Amount = decimal(19,2)
Paid_Month_Year = Date

Sample Record Table
tithings Table
 ___________
|Tithing_ID |
|_____5_____|

Tithingspayment_table
|TP_ID_|_Tithing_ID_|_PaidAmount__|__PaidMonthYear__|
|___1__|______5_____|____10.00____|_____Jan-2014____|
|___2__|______5_____|____10.00____|_____Feb-2014____|
```

Output that I'm looking for( as you can see the TP_ID, Tithing_ID, PaidAmount, PaidMonthYear is duplicated by row.
I want to query this using mysql or PHP

```
 Tithing_ID | TP_ID | Tithing_ID | Paid_Amount |   PaidMonthYear | TP_ID | Tithing_ID | Paid_Amount |  PaidMonthYear  | 
     2      |   1   |     5      |     10.00   |    Jan-2014     |   2   |      5     |     10.00   |     Feb-2014    |
```

### Edit: since I ask that I don't know how I can display this output

```
PaidMonthYear as Jan to Dec
Tithing_ID | Jan   | Feb   | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sept | Oct | Nov | Dec | Year |
     2     | 10.00 | 10.00 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |   0  |  0  |  0  |  0  | 2014 |
```

Because my code display this output

```
Tithing_ID | Jan   | Feb   | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sept | Oct | Nov | Dec | Year |
     2     | 10.00 |   0   |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |   0  |  0  |  0  |  0  | 2014 |
     2     |   0   | 10.00 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |   0  |  0  |  0  |  0  | 2014 |
```

Comment: Use `Joins`, or simple `php logic` to display data in this format.

Comment: I used all possible JOIN but they only return 1 value for each column

Comment: You appear to be confusing data retrieval with data display. Use your presentation layer (PHP) for 'presentation'

Comment: You cannot do it like this. You are duplicating the columns in this way which is not a possible logic. Explain your logic so that we can propose a suitable answer.

Comment: Also 19,2 seems a little ambitious!

Comment: @Strawberry  I update my post please check it again.. I dunno why I put 19,2 maybe I like the number 19.

Comment: @ImNoobSarry you need to do it through PHP now. Hint: Prepare an array of results before you output them to the html.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code would be something like this

```
$year_range= array('2013', '2014', '2015'); //<<give the year range here: say from 2013 to 2015
$months_range = array('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC');

$data_to_display;
foreach($year in $year_range){
foreach($month in $months_range){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tithingspayment_table where PaidMonthYear = '{$month}-{$year}'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$data_to_display[$year][$month] = $row['PaidAmount'];
}
}

//now you just need to display this $data_to_display in html table
//it is a 2 dimensional array that you need to properly display in your table
```